# MS Word Caption & Cross-References & table of figures

Tags: microsoft-word, links, caption, cross-reference

When I click on a link of the table of figures, the link lead to the caption text only, not the image above the text.

For example if I add a figure:
[image]

When a click on the link of the table of figures, the link lead me to:
[image]

If a put the image and the caption on the same line, it works fine, but the problem is when I update the entire table of figures the image apprear next to caption text:
[image]

Is there any clean solution for that particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends what your definition of 'clean' is :-).

If you're willing to put the figure in a table then you can have the caption in the same table (just a different cell) and not have the actual figure show in the list of figures.  If you want to go one step further, you can 'hide' the figure caption in the table by making the text white, and then add a cross-reference under the table to that figure.

See this picture:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I think, there must be a better solution!

Comment: I doubt you'll find it but be sure to post back if you do.  Good luck!